# multispinner in android is not showing deafult text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Refer to following code i have added multi spinner to my android page
 it is not showing default text "select Industry" on the page

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/DP_8"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/DP_8"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/DP_16">

    <com.c2b.util.MultiSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_industry"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_FragmentBecomeMemberModelActor_IndustryHint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/DP_8"
        android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_condensed"
        android:text="Select Industry"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks